# Exponential representation of picard iteration.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

This is a homework question for a first course in real analysis (tiny Rudin) so I'd appreciate hints whilst straight out answers are discouraged due to academic honesty.

I'm given recursively defined:
$M_0=I$, $M_k=I+\int_{t_0}^tA(s)M_{k-1}(s)ds$. Where A is continuous on $[t_0,t_1]$ I've (with a bit of help) shown for matrix M, A (n x n) that this converges uniformly to some function $\Phi(t)$ that satisfies $\Phi' =A\Phi, \,\Phi(t_0)=I$.

Now I need to show that for $det(\Phi)=exp(\int_{t_0}^ttr(A(s)ds)$ and that for scalar continuous $A$, $\Phi=exp(\int_{t_0}^t(A(s)ds)$.

Ive worked a bit on the exponential representation and realized that the recursive definition wasn't much help. However, the differential equation for $\Phi$ reminds very much of one of the definitions of the exponential functions. On the determinant part I hardly know where to begin.

EDIT: Ive just realized contraction mapping could be useful

I'd appreciate any pointers or links to reference literature (I did look at a couple of DE books but they didnt really help).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the scalar case, differentiate $f(t)=\Phi(t)\exp\left(-\int_{t_0}^t A(s)ds\right)$. For the determinant, differentiate $\det(\Phi(t))$. You'll find that $\det(\Phi(t))$ satisfies a simple differential equation.

Comment: Helpful as always, thanks! Ill have a look as soon I'm finished trying an idea. Currently trying another approach (showing lipschitz continuity of $\Phi$) and then proceeding with uniqueness of the solution $\Phi=\exp(\int A)$. Anyway, I'll comment on your suggestion more thoroughly as soon as Ive had the opportunity to try it. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sure you'll solve it!

Comment: Did it both ways now, yours was much more elegant though since I essentially just ripped Picard-Lindelöf's original (the only thing one needed was lipschitz of $A\Phi$ which is easy). Anyway, if you care to repost as an answer I'll accept it.